# How to choose an element that is not in DOM

Tags: selenium, xpath, selector, selenide

Web-site https://account.mail.ru/signup
I try take some position in select "Дата рождения" - "День". Xpath for expant select "День" `//span[text()='День']/ancestor::div[@class='Select-control']`
Then a try select some day, but possition of day don't exist in POM.

Please, help me make correct XPATH.

Comment: I suppose you need to click first on `//div[@data-test-id="birth-date__day"]//span[@class="Select-arrow-zone"]` then use `//div[@class="Select-menu-outer"]//div[@role="option"][i]//span[@class]` to select the day where [i] is the day of your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code to select day from your drop down box :

```
driver.get('https://account.mail.ru/signup')
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='react-select-2--value']//div[@class='Select-placeholder']"))).click()
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Select-option']//span[contains(text(),'12')]"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

To inspect react-select drop down

1. Open chrome browser
2. Open Dev tool
3. Navigate to Elements
4. Select Event Listeners
5. Select blur
6. Click on remove under document

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It real work. But do not tell me how you found this Xpath //div[@class='Select-option']//span[contains(text(),'12')]  https://prnt.sc/s63cr8

Comment: check answer section to inspect react select